# Is there any way to make user-defined functions appear in a totally different namespace?

Tags: python, namespaces, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing some code for a calculus package in python.  Ideally, I would like to support compositions of user-defined functions.  For example, a user could define functions within my SingleVariable class like so:

```
f = SingleVariable('sin(x)')
g = SingleVariable('x+4')
```

and then a composition

```
h = SingleVariable('f(g(x))')
```

These functions can be integrated, differentiated, etc.  The method used to evaluate the function at a point is as follows:

```
def infix_to_function(infix, variable):
    def f(x):
        expression = infix.replace(variable, str(x)).replace('^', '**')
        return eval(expression)
    return f
```

This works fine for functions like `sin` and `ln` because they can be loaded ahead of time so as to be recognized by `eval`.  However, this obviously doesn't work for user-defined functions because they don't exist in the namespace in which the function is actually evaluated.  Returning to the example functions `f` and `g`, i would like a function defined as

```
h = SingleVariable('f(g(x))')
```

to be equivalent to

```
h = SingleVariable('sin(x+4)')
```

I'm writing the package in PyCharm and testing it by importing to a Jupyter Notebook.  I thought about adding the function to a list of some sort when a new `SingleVariable` object is initialized, but that would require somehow grabbing the name of the variable it is being assigned to.

Is there any way to add the functions I define in the Jupyter Notebook to the namespace of the PyCharm package so that they can be recognized by `eval` and have the behavior described?

Comment: Have you considered the `globals()` and `locals()` variables? They may help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing in `globals()` to eval like `eval(expression, globals())`.  I believe Jupyter Notebooks will put any functions that have been defined into the global namespace.

However, using exec() and globals() can cause a lot of problems - so make sure you really understand what you are doing.

It will be a bit more complicated but if you plan to build this out to be very general you may want to look at a lexing libraries like http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/example.html which can help you ensure that the input provide is valid and parsed correctly.

As a small example of the type of problems you can have - based on your sample code I think:

```
f = SingleVariable('sin(s)')
```

may not work the way you expect...